# Can I dual boot Mac mini with Windows 8?

Tags: bootcamp, mac-mini, windows, microsoft

I am planning to buy a new computer. I want to use Visual Studio 2013 and app development for iOS.

Is it possible to make a Mac Mini dual boot with Windows 8? Will I be able to run all Microsoft programs in Windows installation area smoothly?

<sup>I have never used Mac before, so I'd like to get some feedback.</sup>

Comment: My motive is to carry the mac mini from home to office daily as i work at both places. what extra hardware i would need to purchase. My office has windows 8 pc.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can.**

Windows 8 support was provided to Boot Camp in version 5, along with drivers for the Mac hardware.

> Boot Camp 5 adds Windows 8 (64-bit) support. Use the Boot Camp Assistant and a USB drive to install the latest Boot Camp drivers for your computer. These new drivers support both Windows 7 (64-bit) and Windows 8 (64-bit). You should [download](http://support.apple.com/downloads/) the newest drivers available any time you install Windows.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639</sup>

Per the quote above, you can use the Boot Camp Assistant to partition your drive, then install Windows 8 from ISO or disc.

You can find the full guide to installing Windows through Boot Camp on Apple's Help site:

- **[Apple: Boot Camp Help: Install Windows on your Mac](https://help.apple.com/bootcamp/mac/5.0/help/#apdecf0e4b6-b472-438d-881e-57c230b1c250)**

To summarise:

1. Open Boot Camp Assistant from /Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app.
2. Follow the instructions to partition your disk.
3. Let it reboot using your install media.
4. Install Windows normally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sunny, you can.

This is called [BootCamp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1461?viewlocale=en_EN&locale=en_EN) and [here's](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5628) more info about the installation of Windows 8

> Boot Camp lets you run Microsoft Windows on your Mac. Learn how Boot Camp runs Windows and what the installation requirements are.

In addition to above quote, you do not replace your Mac OS X software, but you create a dual-boot.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.